# Where does drupal 7 store the actual content in the database?

Tags: php, database, database-design, drupal

I've opened a database of drupal 7 and looked up in the tables `node`, `node_revisions` and `node types` and couldn't find where drupal stores the actual ***body*** of the node (content).
Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530862

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Oh, I've just found it. In D7 they implemented fields to allow custom fields in content.
So, the node body is considered just a field and its value is now stored in the table field_revision_body (in D7) instead of node_revision (in D6).

If you cite any references for drupal database structure that would be helpful.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: thanks :)
the new drupal Field API is really making the database layout very complex though.

Comment: Thanks for this question and answer. And where are the tags stored ?

Comment: Node body content is stored in four tables: trid_field_data_body, trid_field_data_comment_body, trid_field_revision_body, and trid_field_revision_comment_body.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 7 all the fields in the base table are known as properties, like the title, author_id, current_time_stamp etc. All the other fields like body image and many other which you create are stored in other tables. Actually, Drupal make a separate table for every field in the database and store the primary key of the entity bundle (article, basic page) in that field_table as a foreign key. Basically Drupal make two tables for every field 1: is for storing the data (field_data_[name_of_field]) and 2: is for revision (field_revision_[name_of_field]).