# Drupal Database Structure - Efficient/Inefficient?

Tags: mysql, data-structures, database-design, drupal, database-normalization

I'm certainly no Drupal expert, but I've schemed and built a few databases before, so am puzzled by the structure of a database a 3rd party team is working on that I had Sequel Pro'd into to add some dummy content. I presume the structure wouldn't be apparent if one were to use Drupal's back end GUI, but I don't have creds, just ftp, and ssh access.

I was a bit horrified to see not the single table I would have expected for, say, an Organization, with columns for ID, Name, Address, Email, Zip Code, etc. etc.

Instead, there is a table for each bit of data. That is, a separate table for Name, for Address, for Email, for Zip Code, etc. etc.

That seems, from a logical standpoint, amazingly inefficient. E.g., when an Organization page loads, each bit of data that loads for that org is called from a different table and aggregated, rather than by way of a call to a single table, and all data pulled from one row.

Am I clueless (yes but...) or is this some db structure peculiarity unique to Drupal?

Comment: that's the EAV model for you.. entity, attribute, value. great in theory, horrible in implementation.

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973566

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Drupal stores field content in individual tables so that it will be maximally flexible (for example, if you wanted to re-use those fields on other content types besides "organization" later), it is already in a multi-join table. The tradeoff is performance, which Drupal makes up for with caching and such (for example when that Organization node is loaded, it caches it so that if it's loaded again in that page request it doesn't need to read from those tables again, for example). Since it's a powerful CMS that lets you build and re-build and reorganize how you store your content and fields, it stores the data more flexibly.

Comment: sorry, meant to finish this thought. One issue is that from what I understand, there is no caching without authentication. so any unauthenticated visitors will put what may be undue load on the server. An example of a scenario would be the announcement of a new event which generates much browse traffic. the only reason a user would authenticate (log in) would be to rsvp.