# drupal database structure ..cannot get it

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6

I am a PHP developer and I don't know much about Drupal. Now I have the task to fetch all restaurants names from a Drupal database. I have not been able to find out, which table Drupal is using to store the names of the restaurants.
I am sure it's an easy task for anyone who knows Drupal.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what are the steps you tried? What is the module that you are working with?

Comment: @RumeshEranga Sir,  I have gone through all tables..but could not get any tables that contains 'restaurants " name......
My task is just to get all restaurants  name through direct sql queries...........i know sql but don't know drupal database structure??

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand your question properly. Normally there are no table available about "restaurants" in the Drupal schema. So basically you have to either create a table in your database you create a View. Creating a View would be much efficient.
Google "Drupal Views tutorial" and you will find lot of tutorials on Views. Try that. I am sorry I couldn't give much helpful answer. If you can provide more information about your problem, I might be able to provide much descriptive answer for you.

Comment: @RumeshEranga Thanks for reply......can you help after see clients database ....i will provide you credential ...if yes..please it's really helpful..........

Comment: But looking at your table structure, You are using a module for this purpose. Can you tell the module name?

Comment: @RumeshEranga sir..I don't now about modules in drupal.....

Comment: Hay don't use 'sir' in this forum. can you tell me the steps you performed to install Drupal and what are the configurations you did so far so that I can get a better understanding. If you are following a tutorial or so, please provide the link as well.

Comment: @RumeshEranga i haven't installed Drupal.don't know who installed.......i need only to fetch all restaurants name from database....This database belong to this website
http://www.letseatoutguide.com/

Comment: Do you have all the table names? Only thing you can do is go through every table. Much easier if you could learn Drupal basics about modules.

Comment: yes i have all tables ....complete database...i have gone through all tables..but could not get a single restaurants name.........

Comment: You might have missed some tables then. I'm sorry I will not be able to help you more regarding this question. Hope someone could give you a better answer. Try to learn about Drupal modules. It won't take more than 1 hour to grasp the basics. Specially about Drupal Views. I have a strong feeling that Drupal Views will solve your problem. But first go through the basics.

Comment: Ok Thanks for help me something @RumeshEranga ..i will try to learn Drupal Views.

Comment: Going by just the tables you have shown I would look in field_data_field_company_name. Can't help without further information.

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530862

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you've lost site files or just don't want to mess with Drupal, because it is fairly easy to get data from working copy of site.

This could work to retrieve names, if your restaurant implemented using node:

- Look for `type` column in `node_type` table of a record which most likely is a Restaurant.
- Than go to `node` table and filter by `type` column, which you got on step before this one.

It is more complex if Restaurant is a custom entity provided by other module or a taxonomy term.