# understand data structure in drupal-6 database

Tags: database, drupal-6

I'm trying to convert a drupal-6 website to dotnet ..
I have no idea haw does drupal manipulate the data , I guess that every field is stored in a table.. 
So my question is how can I start exploring the way that drupal manage the data. and where can I find the files that contains the requests or anything related to database structure.

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530862

Answer (score 0):

First you can explore the tables in your database, if you use wamp you can go to phpmyadmin to view it.

Drupal has a master table called "node", every time you create a new content Drupal create a new record in the node table and use primary key to point to the content type table.

To export data you can write custom query, here is an example query

```
$q='SELECT * FROM content_type_yourname type JOIN node node on node.nid = type.nid';  
$arrData = db_query($q);
while($data = db_fetch_object($arrData)){
     dpm($data);
}
```